# Showing certain tags django templates

Tags: html, django, python-2.7, django-templates

If I want to be able to show only certain tags in (say as in a forum post) using django tempalte variables how would I do that?

Say the content of my post is:

```
<div><b>Hell</div>o <i>everyone</i></b>
```

I don't want to show the div tags, but the b and i tags are fine. I know you can use |safe and autoescape but that seems to escape all html. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It seems a bit personalized for your needs what you're looking for. Maybe you can write a custom template tag yourself for doing what you want or have the variable processed in the view and then passed to the template ready to use |safe or {%autoescape%}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **Custom Django Filter** with a **Regular Expression** that does this.

Have a look here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/60/ replace the Regular Expression with what you need to remove the HTMl tags you don't want.